# How Kubernetes TCP Probe handle the fact that TCP handshake is manage by the OS?

Tags: sockets, kubernetes

I'm a bit confuse on how are handle TCP probe with Kubernetes the documentation says:

> A third type of liveness probe uses a TCP socket. With this
> configuration, the kubelet will attempt to open a socket to your
> container on the specified port. If it can establish a connection, the
> container is considered healthy, if it can't it is considered a
> failure.

[source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-tcp-liveness-probe)

But has far as I known, socket client is *connected* before the server perform `accept` on the socket. This TCP handshake is managed by the OS... So how Kubernetes "known" the state of the socket?

To give a little be of context I'm trying to write a unit test in my application (C++) and I cannot figure how K8s handle this, but in k8s it does work as expected (I mean that if I do not accept the connection it will declare my container as *not alive*).

Thank you for your time and consideration!

## Edit 1

Sorry @Steffen Ullrich it take me some time but here a sample of code: https://github.com/quentingodeau/k8s-probe

And then the traces that I get:

```
$ kubectl logs -f $(kubectl get pods | egrep -o 'sample-deployment-[^ ]*')
[2021-07-10 18:46:22.837] [info] Server acccept the client...
[2021-07-10 18:46:23.838] [info] Server acccept the client...
[2021-07-10 18:46:24.840] [info] Server acccept the client...
[2021-07-10 18:46:25.837] [info] Server acccept the client...
[2021-07-10 18:46:26.836] [info] Server acccept the client...
[2021-07-10 18:46:27.839] [info] Server acccept the client...
[2021-07-10 18:46:28.840] [info] Server acccept the client...
[2021-07-10 18:46:29.836] [info] Server acccept the client...
[2021-07-10 18:46:30.843] [info] Server acccept the client...
[2021-07-10 18:46:31.028] [info] Send SIGUSR1
[2021-07-10 18:46:31.836] [info] Server acccept the client...
[2021-07-10 18:46:31.836] [info] Start to not procssing incoming connection
[2021-07-10 18:46:35.855] [info] End of application (signal=15)
```

## Edit 2

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/103632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But has far as I known, socket client is connected before the server perform accept on the socket

While it is true that the connection might be established in the OS before `accept` is called, it is only established after `listen` is called on the socket. If the application is not running (failed to start, crashed) then there is no listening socket so any connection to it will fail. If the listen queue is full since the application fails to handle new connections in time, then the connection will fail too.

This kind of cheap probe is sufficient in many cases but it surely does not handle every case, like making sure that the application responds correctly and responds within the expected time. If such checks are needed more elaborate probes and maybe even application specific probes need to be done.

Comment: thanks, but in fact I thinks that k8s manage to be more precise than that. I have an application that:

* create a server socket (with a pending queue set to one)

* then the application wait by doing: ```while(signal != SIGUSR1) { accept(s); }``` 

* when SIGUSR1 is receive the app do ```while(signal != SIGTERM) { sleep(200ms); }```


And I see k8s killing (SIGTERM) my application after I send SIGUSR1...

Comment: @Quentin: I doubt that k8s does more than I described. I'm not sure what you are seeing just based on this short comment. Please provide the full code for your test program, including output from a run which shows with a timestamp what is happening. Ideally also provide a parallel tcpdump to show the network traffic caused by the probe.

Comment: I directly edit the post I couldn’t reply it exceed the characters limits^^

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks. Based on your output there are 4 seconds between stopping accepting connections and getting killed. It also looks like a connection happened before each second. This means that in the 4 seconds at least 3 connections where tried without getting accepted inside the application. Given the small size of your listen queue it thus happens, what I described in my answer: *"If the __listen queue is full__ since the application fails to handle new connections in time, then the __connection will fail too__."*

Comment: Ok this part I do understand but what I do not is the fact that kubernetes describe its TCP probe `If it can establish a connection, the container is considered healthy, if it can't it is considered a failure.`. And in my understanding it mean that it will open a connection and close it. So how can it reach the maximun pending queue? (also in my code this queue it set to one so in the worse case I will get a 3 sedondes delay, no ?)

Comment: Also, the code I found in k8s let me think that it does as I am describing (but I not an expert by far^^)
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/probe/tcp/tcp.go

Comment: @Quentin: Not only the connections establishment is done in the OS kernel but also the connection shutdown. It can well happen that a client opens and shuts down a connection before `accept` gets called  by the application - all handled by the OS kernel. It still fills up the listen queue though. `acccept`  returns an error for an already closed connection.

Comment: Yes of course but I do not understand what you are trying to say. I get a idea for my missing second (it the `failureThreshold: 1`). But really somethings seen to be strange for me. k8s open a connection every *x* secondes. Two case: 1. the server accept it (I'm stating to wonder who have to close the connection - I was thinking it was k8s but now...) if the server do not close the conexion and k8s does not then the number of connection will only grow. On the other hand if k8s close the connection I do not understand how we reach the maximun (but the code let me think that k8s close the co)...

Comment: @Quentin: k8s closes the connection, there is a clear `conn.Close()` in `DoTCPProbe`. And again: even if no `accept` is called by the server  both the connection establishment and shutdown are done inside the OS kernel. But, the (dead) connection is still added to the listen queue and thus counts against the backlog. And after a number of open+close from the client without accept by the server the listen queue is full and new connections get rejected

Comment: Ok that is now clear for me! I was thinking that the closed socket was removed... (I must have miss read this part during my recherche :()

NB: I think that the k8s documentation must explain a bit of that mess to let people understand how it really work and how their configuration will allow to detect (fast) the non-liveness of their app

Comment: Thank a lot for your time and explanation

Comment: It is helpful to remember that a.container is simply a namespace, similar to an instance of an object.  While there is some added complexity with bridging and other networking features, ultimately the container application is running on the exact same kernel that the host node is using. If you have access to the host you can see how the pods,sockets,fd are just aliases by walking around the /proc filesystem.